# I try to hide the TableView with setHidden to YES, but it is still visible

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I would like to hide a tableview with a button. I set [tableView setHidden:YES]; and when I print the result in the debugger, it says that it is hidden :

```
Printing description of self->pdfTableView:
<UITableView: 0x7fe39f040800; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000241320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000234760>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>
```

The problem, is that I can still see it... Any ideas ?

EDIT :
For test, I put "HIDDEN" to true in the storyboard, and I try to unhide it in the viewDidLoad without success... very strange.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    pdfTableView.dataSource = self;
    pdfTableView.delegate = self;
    pdfTableView = [UITableView new];
    [backBtn setHidden:backBtnHidden];
    [pdfTableView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Are you doing it in a background thread?

Comment: Nope, I do it very simply without background

Comment: The tableView reference seems to be ok as it is printing it's value. Can you share the complete code where you are hiding it?

Comment: I just completed the question. Thank you

Comment: I think with that here "pdfTableView = [UITableView new];" you are breaking the link between the tableview of your storyboard and pdfTableView

Comment: Use the storyboard's outlet pdfTableView instead of creating a new instance through new keyword

Comment: Oh yes, it is right. Thank you very much, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdfTableView = [UITableView new]; was the problem. I removed it.